# How to find oaut_consumer_key in Twitter api?

Tags: c#, winforms, twitter-oauth, xauth

I was downloading a Demo of Twitter `"xAuth with .NET"` from this Article link http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2010/03/twitter-xauth-with-net/

[Click Here To Download Demo](http://voiceoftech.com/downloads/oAuthTwitterDesktopxAuthExampleNET.zip)

when I run this application and give the user name and password then a runtime error generated with `"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: consumerKey"` message.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments in the article, it states that the information for consumer keys etc. are stored in the appliction config and users of the demonstration use their own keys.

Get yourself a key and input the values to the application config.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth ConsumerKey, should be in your application.config (it typically is). You can always go ahead and register for a dev account to get your own ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret from [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) and specify your own. Some more info [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth).

Comment: I generated the consumerKey and consumerSecret and provided in App.config file but after that when I am trying to Run my application then an error is again show with "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." message. 

Please Help me!